# Can somebody please help me with the mistake in algorithm

Tags: c

Problem Link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/PERMUT2

Problem : Getting non ambiguous for all test cases. There is absolutely no problem in executing the program, no errors.

Can you please point out the mistake in my code/algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int index_func(int number, int *array, int x);
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *nums = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
    }
    int j;
    int counter = 0;
    for(j=0; j<n; j++){

        if(nums[j] != index_func(j+1, nums, n)){
            counter = 1;
            break;

        }
    }
    if(counter == 0){
        printf("ambiguous\n");
    }else{
        printf("non ambiguous\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
int index_func(int number, int *array, int x){
    int z, index;
    for(z=0; z<x; z++){
        if(number == array[z]){
            index = z;
            return z;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `int index_func(int number, int *array, int x)` should return something if `number != array[z]` and variable `index` is set, but never used.

Comment: @Michi what if I just place this 'return z;' after the for loop and nothing is done if number != array[z] ?

Comment: Thanks @PaulR , I will try it now!

Comment: Well then, my Answer will probably be...You don't know what you try to do.

Comment: When the number isn't in the array, `index_func` should return an illegal index such as -1, even if that case shouldn't arise in your program. Your problem is that the numbers are from 1 to n, but that the indices are from 0 to n-1. You get that right when passing the index in, but not when you compare the returned index with the current number. (You also write "non ambiguous", when the problem asks you to print "not ambiguous". This will trip the automated results checker.)

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the array start with one, but the indices in C arrays start with 0. A quick fix to your program would be to add one to the returned index when you compare it to the current number:

```
if (nums[j] != index_func(j + 1, nums, n) + 1) ...
```

An alternative solution is to adjust the array data by subtracting one after you scan it, so that the array contains zero-based numbers.

A problem may arise with larger arrays, because every call to `index_func` scans the whole array from the beginning and will traverse half of it on average. The solution will be correct, but very slow.

But you don't have to determine the index to do the comparison. It is sufficient to check whether the number at the index of the current number is the current index. That leads to this function:

```
int is_ambiguous(const int *array, int n)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[array[i] - 1] != i + 1) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Some notes on your original code:

- You should return an invalid index, probably −1, from `index_funct` when the nuber isn't in the array. I know, this shouldn't happen here, but next time you copy and paste the code and the missing return value might bite you.
- You don't really need the variable `index` in `index_funct`. Separating pieces of code into small functions can make the program control easier. Compare the above function `is_ambiguous` with your inline solution with a counter variable and a `break`.
- When you allocate, you must also `free`, which you don't.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int index_func(int number, int *array, int x);
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *nums = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);
    }
    int j;
    int counter = 0;
    for(j=0; j<n-1; j++){
        if((abs(nums[j+1] - nums[j]) != abs(n-1)) && (abs((nums[j+1] - nums[j]) != 1)))
        {
            counter = 0;
        }   
        else
        {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    if(counter == 0){
        printf("ambiguous\n");
    }else{
        printf("non ambiguous\n");
    }
    free(nums);
    return 0;
}
```